# SwiftUI List doesn't update when ViewModel changes

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I've read through a lot of similar questions regarding SwiftUI Lists, but I haven't been able to figure out my particular case, so thank you in advance for your help if you can figure it out.

I have a MacOS app with a NavigationSplitView, where the user selects an item from the left panel, and a list or chart of contents are displayed in the right panel.

```swift
// Relevant views:

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var libraryModel: LibraryModel // @StateObject is held in @main App struct

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            LibraryView(model: libraryModel)
        } detail: {
            ContentMasterView(content: libraryModel.selection) // selection is @Published
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @State var isChartSelected = false
    var content: DataContainer

    var body: some View {
        if isChartSelected {
            MyChartView(content: content)
        } else {
            MyListView(content: content)
                //.id(content.id) // <- see below
        }
    }
}

struct MyListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ListViewModel
    @State var sortingMode = .alphabetical // simple enum with sorting styles    

    init(content: DataContainer) {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ListViewModel(content: content))
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.features, id: \.id) {
                FeatureRow(feature: $0)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Simplified versions of model classes:

class DataContainer: Identifiable {
    func loadContents() -> AnyPublisher<[Feature], Never> { ... }
}

class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var features: [Feature] = []

    init(content: DataContainer) {
        content.loadContents()
            .assign(to: &$features)
    }
}
```

When I select an item from the `LibraryView` (a selectable list, which works fine), `libraryModel.selection` updates and should trigger an update to `DetailView` and then `MyListView`. However, `MyListView` only updates when the first selection is made, and then no updates are reflected on later `LibraryView` selections. If I add `.id(content.id)` to `DetailView` where it is commented out in the code above, the list updates, but other state variables (here, `sortingMode`) for the view are reset, which I'm trying to avoid.

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks :-)

Comment: You are likely missing the basics like Feature being a class you haven’t provided enough info to reproduce. Watch “Demystify SwiftUI”

Comment: Nested ObservableObjects are not supported without manually calling `objectWillChange`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. `DataContainer` isn't `ObservableObject`, but I tried making it that and removing the need for `ListViewModel`, which did the trick. Now `DataContainer` has the Published property for contents instead of `ListViewModel`. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, though-- Could the published property in `ListViewModel` fail to update the view when data was supplied by `AnyPublisher`?

Comment: You're mixing up model data and view data. Remove the selection from the model object. Remove the list View model

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up model data and view data. Remove selection (which is View data) from the library (which is your model) and make the selection be a state in the List view the same as sort. Remove ListViewModel (StateObject is for view data) and use the library model for holding the array of features.

You need to move the sort state up so that you can re-sort the features list whenever sort changes and pass it into the sub view. Usually that is done via a computed property that is passed into child View's init as a let.